# How to push json values in to an array without getting replaced in angular 6?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular6

I have to set values for multiple accordian forms.I have given the code below. I;m trying to push some json response in to an array, so that I can display those array values in to html forms. My array is getting replaced by the last value every time. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

```
historyT: any = [];
public modelaData = {
  name: "",
  age: "",
  operator: "",
};
public historyModel;

 getResponse(){
  this.cs.getResponseValue()
    .subscribe(responseData => {
   this.historyModel = this.modelaData;
   this.responseData.map((val, i) => {
   let a = val.Record.AddDetails;
    a.map((vall, i) => {
            if (isFromOnCreateAccr) {
             this.historyModel.name= a[i].name;
             this.historyModel.age= a[i].age;
             this.historyModel.operator= a[i].operator;
              this.historyT.push(this.historyModel); // Last value is getting replaced here
             }
       })
     })
    })
  }
```

My responsedata from api call would be like below:

```
 [{
   "Key": "S1552115431598",
   "Record": {
   "AdditionalDetails": [{
      "name": "aaa",
      "age": "CHE",
      "operator": "UC1"
     },
    {
      "name": "bb",
      "age": "JAR",
      "operator": "UC2"
    },
   {
      "name": "cc",
      "age": "MUM",
      "operator": "UC3"
    }
  ],
  "Category": "Education",
  "Date": "09-03-2019",
 }
}]
```

Comment: It seems like what you want is `this.historyT = a.map(({ name, age, operator }) => ({ smscTAP: name, circle: age, selectTM: operator }))`. At the moment you're filling the array with references to the same object and you're using `a[i]` when you already have `val`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your reply, but still I cant store the previous values. Only the latest last value is getting stored. Please help

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
historyT: any = [];
public modelaData = {
  name: "",
  age: "",
  operator: "",
};
public historyModel;

 getResponse(){
  this.cs.getResponseValue()
    .subscribe(responseData => {
   this.historyModel = {...this.modelaData}; // <== here just copy object
   this.responseData.map((val, i) => {
   let a = val.Record.AddDetails;
    a.map((vall, i) => {
            if (isFromOnCreateAccr) {
             this.historyModel.name= a[i].name;
             this.historyModel.age= a[i].age;
             this.historyModel.operator= a[i].operator;
              this.historyT.push(this.historyModel); // Last value is getting replaced here
             }
       })
     })
    })
  }
```

My assumption is that **you used one object** and you **were replacing just fields** of this object, so as result you had **an array of the references to one object** which you modified every time. Now you just **copy it** before **filling it with values** and **inserting it into an array**. There are a lot of things that i would implement differently, but this should solve your problem. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But exactly what I need to do here?  this.historyModel = {...this.modelaData};  Would you be kind enough to explain me this pls?

Comment: I explained underneath, so you just pushing into the array the same object and changing fields of that object every time, that means each new time you change field values, you change them for the whole array. With spreading operator you copy object before setting field values and pushing it into an array.